# First element of array undefined after push in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

If I declare an array and then push to it, it will have length "2" not "1", and the first element will be undefined.

```
let myArray = [new Array(2)];
myArray.push(['hi', 'hello']);
alert(myArray[0][0]);
```

This will be undefined:

[image]

However, if I change it to `alert(myArray[1][0]);` it will display what should be the first element of the array.

Why?

Comment: `[new Array(2)]` creates a 2-element array *inside* another array, which will have only 1 element (the array created with `new`).

Comment: And `.push()` of the other array adds a second array to the first outer array. The first inner array is empty, but the second one (at `myArray[1]`) has a two-element array with the first value being "hi".

Comment: Why do you think `['hi', 'hello']` should be the first element? Your array is initialized with one element already.

Comment: Your final array is: `myArray` = `[[undefined, undefined], ['hi', 'hello']]` -> so what do you expect `myArray[0][0]` value to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this:

```
let myArray = [new Array(2)];
myArray.push(['hi', 'hello']);
```

The question is why does the following output undefined:

```
alert(myArray[0][0]);
```

**Answer:**

`new Array(2)` creates an array with two elements and both elements are set to the value of undefined.

`let myArray = [];` creates a new empty array.

`let myArray = [new Array(2)];` creates an array that contains one element. That one element is an array containing two elements whose value is undefined.

`myArray.push(['hi', 'hello']);` adds one element to the end of `myArray`. This one element is an array containing two elements, 'hi' and 'hello'.

At this point, `myArray` looks like this:

```
let myArray = [
    [undefined, undefined],
    ['hi, 'hello'],
];
```

So if you go to `myArray[0]` you get the first element, which is an array, then you go to the first element of that array, which is undefined.

That is why `alert(myArray[0][0]);` outputs undefined.